# Calculate the directional derivative $Xf$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, vector-fields

On $R^3$ consider the vector field $X= x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+ y\frac{\partial}{\partial y} $and the function $f(x, y, z) = x^2+y^2+z^2$.

Calculate the directional derivative $Xf$.

I know how to do the exercise if you have to solve it with a vector or based on a point but not having this information I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You have the definitions of $X$ and $f$. Substitute them into $X f$ and evaluate the expression as you would in a multivariable calculus question.

Comment: @Zhein the result is: $2x^2+2y^2$?

Comment: Exactly, that's the correct answer.

Comment: @JohnnyElCurvas so the directional derivative $Xf$ is $2x^2+2y^2$? It seems too simple...

Comment: Yes, it is simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, you only have to solve in this way:
$$Xf=Xf(x,y,z)=(x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+ y\frac{\partial}{\partial y})(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})$$
From this you find:
$$...=x\frac{\partial x^{2}}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial y^{2}}{\partial y} =2x^{2}+2y^{2}$$

ll other terms are equal to zero.
I hope it will help you.